# Rails 4.1 No route matches [GET] "/controller/action" on link_to :method => :put

Tags: put, link-to, ruby-on-rails-4.1

This is my first RoR project.

My issue was to pass two diffrents requests (delete and put) through a form, so i chose to do the delete in the form and force the link_to function to use put request.

But every time i get : `No route matches [GET] "/examplecontrollers/exampleaction"`

I'm not used to the Ruby/Rails syntax so i tried all of thoses below:

```
<%= link_to raw('<i class="fa fa-check fa-lg"></i>'), {:action => :exampleaction, :id => obj.id}, :class => 'btn', :method => 'put'%>

<%= link_to raw('<i class="fa fa-check fa-lg"></i>'), {:action => :exampleaction, :id => obj.id}, {:class => 'btn', :method => 'put'} %>

<%= link_to raw('<i class="fa fa-check fa-lg"></i>'), examplecontrollers_exampleaction_path(:id => obj.id), {:class => 'btn', :method => 'put'} %>

<%= link_to raw('<i class="fa fa-check fa-lg"></i>'), examplecontrollers_exampleaction_path(:id => obj.id), {:class => 'btn', :method => :put} %>

<%= link_to raw('<i class="fa fa-check fa-lg"></i>'), examplecontrollers_exampleaction_path(:id => obj.id), {:class => 'btn', method: :put} %>
```

In my `routes.rb`, i've tried one by one with:

```
put 'examplecontrollers/exampleaction' => "examplecontrollers#exampleaction", :as => 'exampleaction'
```

or just

```
put 'examplecontrollers/exampleaction'
```

Can you show me the right way to do and/or if you have another way to handle the "multi request form".

Thank you for your help and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in your route.rb just like

```
{map.resources :examplecontrollers, :collection =>{:exampleaction=> :get} }
```